# JQuery - SharePoint List after save

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, jquery

I'm hiding certain fields on sharepoint list based on a dropdown value using jquery. if the value in the dropdown is "No" I hide certain fields, otherwise show them. Upon save the values are saved but I click edit I can see the dropdown value is still "No"(which is right) but the fields I hid are showing. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var value = $("select[title='The Final Performance Review Conversation Took Place?'] option:selected").text(); 

        if (value == "Yes") { 
            $('nobr:contains("Reassign To")').closest('tr').show(); 
            $('nobr:contains("The Final Performance Review Conversation Took Place?")').closest('tr').show(); 
        } 
        else { 
            $('nobr:contains("Reassign To")').closest('tr').hide(); 
            $('nobr:contains("The Final Performance Review Conversation Took Place?")').closest('tr').hide(); 
        } 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you perhaps just add your code when creating a new item (newform) and not while editing the same item which is a different form (editform) ?

Comment: @Christoffer I added it on edit form. it works well for the first until I save then it doesn't preserve the same state when editiing again.

Comment: If you are hiding the fields using a onchange event, that might be the problem. If you debug your code when opening the edit form, you can see if your code are running. Guess you need to check the selected value on document ready and then hide the fields on the go. Can you share your code?

Comment: yes I'm using an onchange event. Let me try selected option and will get back to you. thanks.

Comment: var value = $("select[title='The Final Performance Review Conversation Took Place?'] option:selected").text();
  if (value == "Yes"){
  
  
 $('nobr:contains("Reassign To")').closest('tr').show(); 

  $('nobr:contains("The Final Performance Review Conversation Took Place?")').closest('tr').show();

}
else{  
 $('nobr:contains("Reassign To")').closest('tr').hide(); 

  $('nobr:contains("The Final Performance Review Conversation Took Place?")').closest('tr').hide();
}

Comment: @Christoffer Now I have pasted my code here, still can't get it to work.

Comment: Just tried your code myself, and it works for me. When opening a existing item in editform that has "The final Perf.." set to Yes - both fields are visible. If i open an item that is set to No - Both fields are hidden. Expected behaviour? Hide the fields as soon as the field changes to No?

Comment: yes I'm hiding the fields as soon as the field value changes to No. So it works first time but second time I edit again with saved value of "No", when the form opens up it opens with those, suppose to be hidden fields shown. So I want the the form to maintain the same state I saved it as...

Comment: Ah, I think you should hide the fields by default and then check the value. If yes, show, else, hide. And then add an onChange event to hide them if the value changes and are equal to Yes. I prefer hiding, then evaluate/re-evaluate.

Comment: @Christoffer I just can't this thing to work at all, when I use the selected value option, it doesn't work when I change the value. So what I need: I need to be able to save the form and when I edit it must show the values I submitted. basically the form works before I save it, but once I edit after save it comes back with the correct dropdown value but all the logic doesn't apply until I go to the dropdown change values again. Please help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87986/discussion-between-christoffer-and-vusi85).